# parse through nested xml

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, nested

i have a rather extensive question, so thanks to everyone who is with me til the end.
consider the following:
i have a given xml file, that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<format> 
   <bold> 
   Hi, this is a bold text 
      <underline>
      with underlined 
      </underline>
      and 
      <italic>
      italic
      </italic>
  segments.
  </bold>
</format>
```

what the environments intend, should be clear: everything within the bold environment, should be written **bold**, everything within bold and italic, should be written ***bold and italic*** and so on. i hope you get the idea.

what i want now, is to parse this xml file in order to set a textstyle for every segment, that can be formatted afterwards. but i have problems with e.g. the nested use of bold. how do i handle this problem?
an idea that i have gotten is to use a stack and push a style onto this stack as long as it is not being closed in the xml and remove it otherwise. but i have no idea how to implement this one either.

thank you in advance, newbie

Comment: What have you tried? Which environment/programming language do you use? ....

Comment: i have tried using [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html#stax) and altered the according parts to what i need. therefore i am using java to parse through the xml.